# Popup window android is not setting above view in android?

Tags: android, android-popupwindow

At the bottom right of the page I have a view on whose click I am opening the pop up window. But it opens up overlapping the view. I want it to open above the view.

Below are the screenshots.

[image]

[image]

And below is my code
Creating the window as

```
seasonEpisodePopUpWindow = new PopupWindow(this);
        seasonEpisodePopUpWindow.setContentView(seasonEpisodeView);
        seasonEpisodePopUpWindow.setHeight(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        seasonEpisodeView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        seasonEpisodePopUpWindow.setWidth(seasonEpisodeView.getMeasuredWidth() * 2);
```

And this is how I am opening the pop up window

```
int[] viewLocation = new int[2];
    anchorView.getLocationOnScreen(viewLocation);
    if (!seasonEpisodePopUpWindow.isShowing()) {
        seasonEpisodePopUpWindow.showAtLocation(anchorView, Gravity.TOP, viewLocation[0], viewLocation[1] - anchorView.getHeight());
    }
```

How do I open the view above my view?

Comment: is `anchorView.getHeight() != 0` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

was able to solve this with below

```
seasonEpisodePopUpWindow.showAtLocation(anchorView, Gravity.BOTTOM, viewLocation[0], anchorView.getHeight());
```